# ansible with_items pass variables from outside file

Tags: ansible

I just want to pass list of rpm packages in a yml file and call it in with_items inside my tasks. 
Which format the yml file should be. Please help me. I googled a lot, still being confused. I need to achieve so that I could change only the package names in outside file, without changing the main file.

Ex: `files.yaml`

```
---
- vars:
    modules:
      - firmware-system-p89-2.56_2018_01_22-1.1.i386.rpm
      - firmware-smartarray-ea3138d8e8-6.30-1.1.x86_64.rpm
```

=> passing to `with_items` in another file

```
---
- name: List required packages
  include_vars:
    -files.yml
  set_fact: pkglist="{{ item}}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ modules }}"
  register: pkglist_result


    Comment:
```

Thanks a lot. that helps. 
I did just this to finally accomplish. I wasn't trying right. But I mentioned just the name of the packages in files.yml and placed the real packages in files directory where tasks directory resides.

```
- name: List required packages
  include_vars: files.yml
  register: pkglist_result

- name: make a list
  set_fact: pkg_list="{{ pkglist_result.ansible_facts.modules}}"

- debug: var=pkg_list
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`files.yml`:

```
---
modules:
  - firmware-system-p89-2.56_2018_01_22-1.1.i386.rpm
  - firmware-smartarray-ea3138d8e8-6.30-1.1.x86_64.rpm
```

example playbook:

```
---
- hosts: my_hosts
  vars_files:
    - files.yml
  tasks:
    - name: print module name one by one
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ modules }}"
```

Comment: So, this one works but when I try to use it inside a task it throws error like :
      ERROR! 'vars_files' is not a valid attribute for a Task. 
Hence I tried with include_vars but it is not working. I expect it to be simple but am missing something on this.

Comment: That was silly. The below worked simple.

          include_vars: files.yml
          register: pkglist_result

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative you can do by using lookup ([more info](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_lookups.html)).

```
with_items: "{{ lookup('file', '../files/mylist.json') }}"
```